# Servletrequest returns null sessions

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, servlets, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am getting a strange error where the session I get from the request is sometimes null. Code looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/login")
public class GetLogin {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
    public Response login(){
        final HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession(true);
        sessionId = session.getId();//Sometimes gives nullpointer Exceptions
    .....//Rest works fine if that step holds
```

When I call to get the session id I sometimes get a nullpointer exception. Why is that? Is there anything I can do to stop that? I can repeat the exact same call over and over and it randomly creates nullpointer exceptions due to that while other times it works just fine. I have tried doing this all sort of ways, with methods waiting for it to get ready and so on. What I learned was that if it don't get ready instantly it will never get ready.

The get cookies method on the request do occasionally fail as well bit that is easy to work around by just taking the cookies as arguments in the function. Also it seems like I can get around this by telling the frontend to repeat the call if the first one failed, the second call always succeeds then for some reason. But that feels like a dirty solution, so I really want to fix this...

Any ideas?

Edit: Apparently if I let it fail it fails every other time, but if I handle it so that the servlet don't crash it fails 4 times in a row and then succeeds once. I tried doing this on a fresh install, I took the standard netbeans example rest webapp and just added the HttpRequest to it and then printed out the session id. If anyone got this to work please show me how...

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I tried exact same code with glassfish 3 and it worked perfectly then. I will see if there are any updates to glassfish 4 that fixes this, or I will downgrade.

Comment: Otherwise you shall post bug report